# Which of these two AR queries is more efficient? (ie. is it better to outsource some query work to Ruby )

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
  @users = Hash.new
  @users[:count] = User.count(:all, :joins => my_join, :conditions => my_conditions)
  @users[:data] = User.find(:all, :joins => my_join, :conditions => my_conditions)
```

or

```
  @users = Hash.new
  @users[:data] = User.find(:all, :joins => my_join, :conditions => my_conditions)
  @users[:count] = @users[:data].count
```

It seems like the first option consists of two database queries (which from what I read is expensive) while in the second one, we only make one database query and do the counting work at the Ruby level.

Which one is more efficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second one is better, since, just like you said, it saves a database query.

p.s.

Please be careful if you use some new finder methods introduced in Rails 3, then calling `count` after would fire a `COUNT(*)` query:

```rb
users = User.where(...)    # SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ...
users_count = users.count  # SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" WHERE ...
```

To prevent that, you might want to call `size`:

```rb
users = User.where(...)   # SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ...
users_count = users.size  # No database query
```

Comment: thanks for answering Domon. Let me see what a few others say before I close this.

Comment: You might not get many more answers because this one covers it.